# Can I use Copay like Bitgo?

Tags: bitcore, copay, bitgo

I need to use multisig wallet on my online service. The most suitable service for me is Bitgo, but it is very expensive. Commission 0.25% on the withdrawal.
Can I use the Copay wallet for such tasks? I would not want to run my own Bitcore server. I can not figure out how to send API requests to the Bitcore server from Bitpay.

Answer (score 1):

There is a multisig option for wallets.  Bitgo has a much more nuanced way to handle multisig.  Better for some environments, but not so good for others.  Try creating a multisig wallet in Copay and seeing if it will work for you.  You can do it across a few devices to make sure you see how it works